# Why on earth is my image not showing up on login page?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

This is got to be one of most frustrating issues I have had.

On my login page, I have this:

```
   <table id="Table2" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" bgcolor="#336699" border="0">
    <tr>
     <td><asp:hyperlink id="logo" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/logon.jpg" 
             Border="0" NavigateUrl="#" BorderStyle="None"></asp:hyperlink></td>
    </tr>
 </table>
```

All we needed is for the image to show up as soon as that page loads.

It doesn't. It shows the red X.

I have tried the following as well but none of them works.

```
<img src="~/images/logon.jpg" width="330" height="75" runat="server" />
```

and this:

```
<img src="images/logon.jpg" width="330" height="75" runat="server" />
```

I can see them when in design mode but when I run the app, no image.

Comment: Right-click in the red x then select Inspect element. Double check on the generated path to give you an idea if the path is correct..

Comment: that's the most annoying part. The path is correct. I have done that a ton of times.

Comment: So then the path itself loads fine in the browser if you enter it in the address bar directly?

Comment: After you right-click the picture and get the path as resolved by IIS, can you load the picture from that path in your browser?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Likely an authentication issue. In design mode you are reading directly from the file system. In the browser, IIS is processing the request and reading the files from the app directory.

Make sure you have a section in your web.config that allows anonymous access to your images folder.

To verify that this is the issue, launch the Chrome console (Press F12) and see what kind of error your are getting. 404, 403, etc...

**EDIT**

I mean something like this:

```
   <location path="images">
      <system.web>
         <authorization>
            <allow users="*"/>
         </authorization>
      </system.web>
   </location>
```

Comment: Here is an example of the link when I right-click the image: http://localhost:1346/cControl/images/logon.jpg. Which is correct. However, when I load it in a separate url, it loads entire login screen, rather than the image itself.

If this helps, this is the url I get when I load the login page.

It is a redirect from default.aspx page.

http://localhost:1346/cControl/logon.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fcControl%2fDefault.aspx

But it doesn't matter whether I load it directly from login or via redirect, I get same no image red X.

Comment: `However, when I load it in a separate url, it loads entire login screen, rather than the image itself... ` which confirms that the issue is related to authentication. It's displaying the login screen instead of the image because it detects that you are not authenticated and redirecting you to the login screen. As I said. Include in your web.config a section to allow anonymous access to the images folder. I will post an example shortly.

Comment: thank you. there is one problem though, users are getting authenticated via Active Directory and initially, had to set authorization to `<deny users="?" />' Now, it is creating an error indicating authenticationTyoe is not declared. Problem has to do with location path="images". If I remove it, the errors goe away.

Comment: Any reason not to use integrated windows auth instead? If you are manually writing the code to authenticate against an LDAP server, you will need to enable Forms auth.

Comment: I am doing just that with the code below:
    `<authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="logon.aspx" name="adAuthCookie" timeout="60"
        path="/">
      </forms>`

Comment: Atlease you pointed me to the problem. I just need to figure out a way to solve it.
Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Also make sure 'Static Content' is checked when setting up IIS in Windows 10:

[image]

Internet Information Services -> World Wide Web Services -> Common HTTP Features -> Check Static Content

[image]

AND verify:

[image]

Thanks Co-workers (MMA and CL)

Answer (score 0):

When running your website have you tried going to your image? I.e mywebsite.com/images/logon.jpg ..?
If that works then try showing the image with just a img tab:

```
<img src="../images/logon.jpg" alt="my image">
```

If that doesn't work try loading the site on IIS and see if it makes a difference

Answer (score 0):

My advice is to work backwards.

First, figure out what URL *should* be used.  Get the image to load correctly by entering it in the address bar of your browser.

Second, look at the generated source code to see where these URLs diverge.

Answer (score 0):

**TRY THIS IN YOUR  WEB CONFIG. FILE**

```
<location path="images">    
         <system.web>
     <authorization>
        <allow users="?"/>
     </authorization>
  </system.web>
```